# Using Let to build multiple instances of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm trying to run a test on will_paginate. I know that it technically works, but I can't get the spec to work because of my inability to create multiple records. I'm using Capybara and Rspec on with Ruby on Rails.

Here is what I have in my feature spec.

```
RSpec.describe "Users Index", type: :feature do
 describe "Pagination" do 
  let(:valid_user) { create(:user, name: "Mogli") }
  let(:other_user) { create(:user, 50) }

   it "successfully paginates" do
    log_in_as_feature(valid_user)
    visit users_path
    puts URI.parse(current_url)
    expect(page).to have_css('div.pagination')
    expect(page).to have_link(href: user_path(valid_user), text: valid_user.name)
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      expect(page).to have_link(href: user_path(user), text: user.name)
      unless user == valid_user
        expect(page).to have_link(href: user_path(user), text: "delete")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

My factory is simple:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 sequence(:name) { |n| "Person#{n}" }

  factory :user do
   name
   email { "#{name}@example.com" }
   password "foobar"
   password_confirmation "foobar"
   activated true
   activated_at Time.zone.now
  end
end
```

My fourth line is the culprit. It's not actually building the users. I tried to use a `FactoryGirl.create(:user, 50)`, but that ends up breaking 27 tests across the board, and I have to reset the test database.

I don't know how else to create more than one dummy user at once, all the while keeping Mogli as first. Any insight is appreciated.

Edit: If I commented the have_css test, then my tests pass.

Here is the error of the div

`1) Users Index Pagination successfully paginates
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('div.pagination')
       expected to find css "div.pagination" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/users_index_spec.rb:13:in`block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 0.82368 seconds (files took 2.17 seconds to load)`

EDIT: adding my partial and index.html.erb view.

My view just renders @users partial

which is:

```
1 <li>
2   <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
3   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
4   <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
5     | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
6                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
7   <% end %>
8
9 </li>
```

Comment: I think `let(:other_user) { create(:user, 50) }` should be like `let(:other_user) { create(:user, name: 'another name') `}`

Comment: The error you just updated in your question means that div is not visible on the page.  Look at `page.html` and see what is actually on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example has a few issues.  As mentioned by others `let` is lazily evaluated, so to create objects that aren't directly referenced you would need to use `let!`.  Additionally, FactoryGirl's `create` doesn't take a number of records to produce, you need `create_list` for that.  Finally, Capybara's `have_link` takes the text of the link you're looking for as the first parameter so there's no need to pass a `:text` option

```
RSpec.describe "Users Index", type: :feature do
 describe "Pagination" do 
  let!(:valid_user) { create(:user, name: "Mogli") }
  let!(:other_users) { create_list(:user, 50) }

   it "successfully paginates" do
    log_in_as_feature(valid_user)
    visit users_path
    puts URI.parse(current_url)
    expect(page).to have_css('div.pagination')
    expect(page).to have_link(valid_user.name, href: user_path(valid_user))
    User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
      expect(page).to have_link(user.name, href: user_path(user))
      expect(page).to have_link("delete", href: user_path(user)) unless user == valid_user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that Capybara worked that way. 

I also tried the Let! option under my first let, and while that works, it loses my valid_user's name in the process. 

"Users Index Pagination successfully paginates
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_link(valid_user.name, href: user_path(valid_user))
       expected to find link "Mogli" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/users_index_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'"

Comment: @user12398736 That would tend to mean that link isn't actually on the page.  Are you sure valid_user is actually on the first paginated page? Since the `let(:valid_user` block isn't evaluated until `valid_user` is called it would probably be on the second page.  To fix that you would have to use `let!` in both cases - answer updated

Comment: I think it's supposed to. 

My index.html.erb:
    1 <% provide(:title, 'All Users') %>
    2 <h1>All Users</h1>
    3
    4 <%= will_paginate %>
    5 <ul class="users">
    6   <%= render @users %>
    7 </ul>
    8 <%= will_paginate %>

and my partial

    1 <li>
    2   <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
    3   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    4   <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    5     | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
    6                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    7   <% end %>
    8
    9 </li>

Comment: Which ones are on which page would depend on the sort order of the returned records.  By changing the first `let` to `let!` as well it will create valid_user before other_users - so you need to make sure @users is sorting the records by id or created_at date

Comment: It's sorting by id. 

@user = User.find(params[:id])

maybe I should reset the test database and redo? That would change the order of creation.

-edit: that fixed the valid_user error, but it removed the "delete" option. I gave valid_user the admin privilege and now all tests pass. 

thank you very much.

Comment: @user12398736 You should have your tests setup to reset the test database after every test, and that code doesn't show that \@users is sorted by id, that finds a single user by id.

Comment: Do you have a resource on how to set up the tests to reset the test database after every test? Also, where would I look to find out how it is sorted. Again, thank you for the info.

Comment: @user12398736 If using the rack_test driver with Capybara or are on rails 5.1+ you can just enable use_transactional_fixtures in your RSpec config.  If using a JS capable driver on rails <= 5.0 you'll need to configure database_cleaner - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example .  For the sorting you need to look at your controller where `@users` is assigned.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `let` is [lazy-evaluated](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). That means it will not be evaluated until the moment you call it in your spec. You don't use `other_user` in your spec, so it is not evaluated.

Secondly, if you want to create a list of 50 users to set up your spec, use a `before` block:

```
before do
  # using create_list
  create_list(:user, 50)

  # OR just
  50.times { create(:user) }
end

it "successfully paginates" do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: When I use the before do, and I comment the other tests out except for pagination, then it passes. Once I make all tests active, then it fails with "Users Index Pagination successfully paginates
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_link(valid_user.name, href: user_path(valid_user))
       expected to find link "Mogli" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/users_index_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already by Jan, `let` is lazily-evaluated. If you don't use `other_user`, it will never be created. There's an eager-counterpart, though.

```
let!(:other_user) { create(:user, 50) }
```

This one is always created.